# In R, Find the Correlation Matrix for each Sub-Test

Tags: r, list, matrix, subset, correlation

I have a data set with 30 variables that make up three different scales (10 items each). Considering a small scale example, I wrote a function (with help from y'all) that takes the correlation matrix from this...

```
    C1  C2  A1  A2  N1  N2
C1  1  .36 .64 .47 .36 .43  
C2 .36  1  .27 .43 .40 .47
A1 .64 .27  1  .50 .49 .33
A2 .47 .43 .50   1 .47 .37
N1 .36 .40 .49 .47  1  .41
N2 .43 .47 .33 .37 .41  1
```

...to this:

```
    C1  C2  A1  A2  N1  N2
C1  1  .36  0   0   0   0  
C2 .36  1   0   0   0   0
A1  0  0    1  .50  0   0
A2  0  0   .50  1   0   0
N1  0  0    0   0   1  .41
N2  0  0    0   0  .41  1
```

My goal now is to store this correlation matrix (based on each of the three different scales) into a list containing three matrices. The final output should look like the following:

```
'1'
    C1  C2
C1  1  .36 
C2 .36  1

'2'
    A1  A2
A1  1  .50 
A2 .50  1 

'3'
    N1  N2
N1  1  .41
N2 .41  1
```

I'd imagine running a for loop and storing the result in a list would be best. Sadly, I'm drawing blanks on where to even start. However, what is important is that the code that generates the above result is generalizable to be utilized on data sets that contain two, three (like this instance), four, or more subscales.

I have some additional information to add. Below is the function used to replace values in the matrix with 0s. Not the parameters of the of the variables are as follows:

```
num.vars <- 6; num.subscales <- 3; cor.d <- is the table from above

# Find correlation matrix of each sub-test
temp <- seq(1, num.vars, 1)
temp.factors <- split(temp, cut(temp, num.subscales, labels=FALSE))
temp.names <- names(d)

temp.factors <- lapply(temp.factors, function(x) temp.names[x])

facReplace <- function(m, f) {
  x <- do.call("c", f)
  m1 <- data.frame(m)
  row.names(m1) <- x
  names(m1) <- x
  for (i in 1:length(f)) {
    for (j in 1:length(x)) {
      for (k in 1:length(x)) {
        tempfac <- do.call("c", f[i])
        temprow <- x[j]
        tempcol <- x[k]
        if (!(temprow %in% tempfac) & (tempcol %in% tempfac)) (m1[j, k] <- 0)
      }
    }
  }
  return(m1)
}
sub.cor.matrix <- as.matrix(facReplace(cor.d, temp.factors))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

`scales_name` gets the unique scale attribute by removing the trailing numbers. You can just subset and filter the `df` to get your list of `data.frame`

```
> df <- read.table(text = "    C1  C2  A1  A2  N1  N2
+ C1  1  .36 .64 .47 .36 .43  
+            C2 .36  1  .27 .43 .40 .47
+            A1 .64 .27  1  .50 .49 .33
+            A2 .47 .43 .50   1 .47 .37
+            N1 .36 .40 .49 .47  1  .41
+            N2 .43 .47 .33 .37 .41  1", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
> 
> scales_name <- unique(gsub("[:0-9:]", "", colnames(df)))
> 
> list_cor_mat <- list()
> for (scale_tmp in scales_name) {
+   list_cor_mat <- c(list_cor_mat,
+     list(df[grepl(scale_tmp,rownames(df)), grepl(scale_tmp,colnames(df))])
+   )
+ }
> 
> names(list_cor_mat) <- scales_name
> list_cor_mat
$C
     C1   C2
C1 1.00 0.36
C2 0.36 1.00

$A
    A1  A2
A1 1.0 0.5
A2 0.5 1.0

$N
     N1   N2
N1 1.00 0.41
N2 0.41 1.00
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thank you, raymkchow!